# SDL2 - SDL_PollEvent slower on Ubuntu/Mac OS X than Windows

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl-2

I wrote a Space Invaders emulator in C++ using SDL2 only for creating the game window and for playing sounds (sdl2_mixer). On Windows the emulator works at 60 FPS (I can change this value to whatever I want and it works without any problem) but if I build it on Ubuntu or Mac OS X the game is unplayable (maybe 10% of the wanted FPS).

Is there an explanation for this?

- Renderer name on Ubuntu: **opengl**
- Renderer name on Windows: **direct3d**
- Renderer flags is **0x0a** both on Ubuntu than Windows.

Compiled with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp spaceinvadersmachine.cpp intel8080.cpp -lSDL2 -lSDL2_mixer -I/usr/include/SDL2 -I/usr/include/SDL2_mixer -D_REENTRANT -o spaceinvaders.app
```

Here some code:

**// MAIN loop**

```
while (!quitEmulator)
{
    // Handle events on queue
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&events) == 1)
    {
        switch (events.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
        {
            // Game's window has been closed
            quitEmulator = true;
            break;
        }
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        {
            // Set magnification to 1x
            if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_1)
            {
                machine.magnificationFactor = 1.0;
                machine.magnificationRequest = true;
            }

            // Save game request
            if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_2)
            {
                machine.saveGameRequest = true;
            }

            // Load game request
            if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_3)
            {
                machine.loadGameRequest = true;
            }

            // Set magnification to 4x
            if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_4)
            {
                machine.magnificationFactor = 2.0;
                machine.magnificationRequest = true;
            }

            // Set bases dipswitch request
            if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_7)
            {
                machine.dipBasesRequest = true;
            }

            // Set bonus base dipswitch request
            if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_8)
            {
                machine.dipBonusBaseRequest = true;
            }

            // Set magnification to 9x
            if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_9)
            {
                machine.magnificationFactor = 3.0;
                machine.magnificationRequest = true;
            }

            // Set coin informations dipswitch request
            if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_i)
            {
                machine.dipCoinInfoRequest = true;
            }

            // Game paused
            if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_p)
            {
                gamePaused = !gamePaused;
                if (gamePaused)
                    cout << "INFO: Game paused!\n";
                else
                    cout << "INFO: Game resumed!\n";
            }

            // Reset request
            if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_r)
            {
                machine.resetRequest = true;
            }

            // Change color mode
            if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_c)
            {
                machine.coloredFrame = !machine.coloredFrame;

                if (machine.coloredFrame)
                    cout << "INFO: Color mode set to RGB\n";
                else
                    cout << "INFO: Color mode set to B/W\n";
            }

            break;
        }
        }
    }

    if (!gamePaused)
    {
        // Check keyboard inputs
        SDL_PumpEvents();
        machine.checkKeyboardInput();

        // Set bases dipswitch if requested
        if (machine.dipBasesRequest)
        {
            machine.setBasesDipswitch();
        }

        // Set bonus base dipswitch if requested
        if (machine.dipBonusBaseRequest)
        {
            machine.setBonusBaseDipswitch();
        }

        // Set coin informations dipswitch if requested
        if (machine.dipCoinInfoRequest)
        {
            machine.setCoinInfoDipswitch();
        }

        // Change magnification factor if requested
        if (machine.magnificationRequest)
        {
            machine.setMagnification();
        }

        // Check for interrupt
        if (CPUInterruptDeltaCycles >= cyclePerInterrupt)
        {
            CPUInterruptDeltaCycles = 0;

            machine.interruptRequest = true;

            if (machine.lastInterruptNumber == 1) // RST 1
            {
                machine.interruptNumber = 2; // RST 2
            }
            else // RST 2
            {
                machine.interruptNumber = 1; // RST 1
            }

            machine.lastInterruptNumber = machine.interruptNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            machine.interruptRequest = false;
        }

        // Execute next instruction
        CPU.executeROM(machine.interruptRequest, machine.interruptNumber);

        // Increments CPU's cycle counters
        CPUDeltaCycles += CPU.CPUCycles;
        CPUInterruptDeltaCycles += CPU.CPUCycles;

        // Check if OPCode is known
        if (CPU.unimplementedOPCode)
            quitEmulator = true;

        // Check for I/O
        machine.checkIO();

        // Check if a frame must be drawn
        // Save and Load if requested
        if (CPUDeltaCycles >= cyclePerFrame)
        {
            CPUDeltaCycles = 0;
            machine.createFrame();
            machine.showFrame();
            drewFrames += 1;

            while ((SDL_GetTicks() - lastFPSSynchronization) < frameTimeInterval)
            {
                // Waiting
                ;
            }

            lastFPSSynchronization = SDL_GetTicks();

            if (machine.saveGameRequest)
            {
                machine.saveGameRequest = false;
                machine.saveGame(CPUInterruptDeltaCycles);
            }

            if (machine.loadGameRequest)
            {
                machine.loadGameRequest = false;
                machine.loadGame(CPUInterruptDeltaCycles);

                // Remove pending keyboard events
                SDL_FlushEvent(SDL_KEYDOWN);
                SDL_FlushEvent(SDL_KEYUP);
                SDL_PumpEvents();
            }
        }

        // Reset if requested
        if (machine.resetRequest)
        {
            machine.resetRequest = false;
            machine.resetMachine();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to comment out the part where the frame is created (so no frame update on the window) and the game remains slow (the audio is still playing), so the problem is not inside frame creation function.

I found that the problem are `SDL_PumpEvents` and `SDL_PollEvent` functions. It is possible to eliminate the first one in the main loop but obviously not the second one. Why poll events is too slow? Events number are the same both on Windows then Ubuntu

Comment: Perhaps it's correctly using the GPU on windows and falling back to a software renderer on *nix. Call `SDL_GetRendererInfo` and check the resulting struct.

Comment: Do some profiling.

Comment: The explanation might be in the code, which you don't show us. Please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Did you enable optimizations? How are you drawing? Show some code.

Comment: Thanks for yours replies, I didn't add code because I tried to comment out the part where the frame is created (so no update on the window) and the game remains slow (the audio is still playing). I add some code

Comment: Added some code

Comment: Is it normal to create a surface and texture every frame?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, on the emulator I have a raw data on RAM. I also tried to use SDL_UpdateTexture avoiding to create a surface on each loop, nothing changes. On Windows the game is fast, on Ubuntu/Mac OS X is slow

Comment: Renderer flags is 0x0a both on Windows than Ubuntu

Comment: I suggest using a profiler.

Comment: How did you compile your code?

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp spaceinvadersmachine.cpp intel8080.cpp -lSDL2 -lSDL2_mixer -I/usr/include/SDL2 -I/usr/include/SDL2_mixer -D_REENTRANT -o app.exe`

Comment: Add `-O2` to enable optimizations.

Comment: @Botje It is better but still unplayable

Comment: Please run a profiler, find the parts of the program that are actually slower than you expect and then come back once you've found where the problem is but still can't figure out what it is or how to fix it.

Comment: @Cubic How? Some tips?

Comment: @Francesco you can profile your program with callgrind: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html; during profiling it'll be 10-1000 times slower than it normally would be, but it'll slow everything down roughly equally so you can still use the proportions. Otherwise, just use the timing stuff from `<chrono>` and do it manually, which'll be faster but more tedious to set up.

Comment: I found that the problem are `SDL_PumpEvents` and `SDL_PollEvent` functions. It is possible to eliminate the first one in the main loop but obviously not the second one. Why poll events is too slow? Events number are the same both on Windows and Ubuntu

Comment: I found a solution and edited the question, in which way can I put this question out of hold state???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote before the problem is that **SDL_PollEvent function is slower on Ubuntu than on Windows**.

This has pointed my attention on main loop and I found a problem: *new events polling is done on each loop on main while cycle* instead of on each frame (60 times per seconds) so this heavily slowdown the execution. This is not a problem on Windows because there is a sufficient time for drawing a frame each 16 ms but it is a problem on Ubuntu where SDL_PollEvent is slower and the frame is drawn not in time.

So **I moved the polling handler in order to check for a user input only 60 times per second. Don't put the polling function inside the main while loop without a robust control!**

Here the new code:

```
while (!quitEmulator)
{
    if (!gamePaused)
    {
        // Check keyboard inputs
        machine.checkKeyboardInput();

        // Set bases dipswitch if requested
        if (machine.dipBasesRequest)
        {
            machine.setBasesDipswitch();
        }

        // Set bonus base dipswitch if requested
        if (machine.dipBonusBaseRequest)
        {
            machine.setBonusBaseDipswitch();
        }

        // Set coin informations dipswitch if requested
        if (machine.dipCoinInfoRequest)
        {
            machine.setCoinInfoDipswitch();
        }

        // Change magnification factor if requested
        if (machine.magnificationRequest)
        {
            machine.setMagnification();
        }

        // Check for interrupt
        if (CPUInterruptDeltaCycles >= cyclePerInterrupt)
        {
            CPUInterruptDeltaCycles = 0;

            machine.interruptRequest = true;

            if (machine.lastInterruptNumber == 1) // RST 1
            {
                machine.interruptNumber = 2; // RST 2
            }
            else // RST 2
            {
                machine.interruptNumber = 1; // RST 1
            }

            machine.lastInterruptNumber = machine.interruptNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            machine.interruptRequest = false;
        }

        // Execute next instruction
        CPU.executeROM(machine.interruptRequest, machine.interruptNumber);

        // Increments CPU's cycle counters
        CPUDeltaCycles += CPU.CPUCycles;
        CPUInterruptDeltaCycles += CPU.CPUCycles;

        // Check if OPCode is known
        if (CPU.unimplementedOPCode)
            quitEmulator = true;

        // Check for I/O
        machine.checkIO();

        // Check if a frame must be drawn
        // Save and Load if requested
        if (CPUDeltaCycles >= cyclePerFrame)
        {
            CPUDeltaCycles = 0;
            // Handle events on queue
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&events) == 1)
            {
                switch (events.type)
                {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                {
                    // Game's window has been closed
                    quitEmulator = true;
                    break;
                }
                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                {
                    // Set magnification to 1x
                    if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_1)
                    {
                        machine.magnificationFactor = 1.0;
                        machine.magnificationRequest = true;
                    }

                    // Save game request
                    if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_2)
                    {
                        machine.saveGameRequest = true;
                    }

                    // Load game request
                    if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_3)
                    {
                        machine.loadGameRequest = true;
                    }

                    // Set magnification to 4x
                    if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_4)
                    {
                        machine.magnificationFactor = 2.0;
                        machine.magnificationRequest = true;
                    }

                    // Set bases dipswitch request
                    if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_7)
                    {
                        machine.dipBasesRequest = true;
                    }

                    // Set bonus base dipswitch request
                    if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_8)
                    {
                        machine.dipBonusBaseRequest = true;
                    }

                    // Set magnification to 9x
                    if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_9)
                    {
                        machine.magnificationFactor = 3.0;
                        machine.magnificationRequest = true;
                    }

                    // Set coin informations dipswitch request
                    if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_i)
                    {
                        machine.dipCoinInfoRequest = true;
                    }

                    // Game paused
                    if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_p)
                    {
                        gamePaused = !gamePaused;
                        if (gamePaused)
                            cout << "INFO: Game paused!\n";
                        else
                            cout << "INFO: Game resumed!\n";
                    }

                    // Reset request
                    if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_r)
                    {
                        machine.resetRequest = true;
                    }

                    // Change color mode
                    if (events.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_c)
                    {
                        machine.coloredFrame = !machine.coloredFrame;

                        if (machine.coloredFrame)
                            cout << "INFO: Color mode set to RGB\n";
                        else
                            cout << "INFO: Color mode set to B/W\n";
                    }

                    break;
                }
                }
            }
            machine.createFrame();
            machine.showFrame();
            drewFrames += 1;

            while ((SDL_GetTicks() - lastFPSSynchronization) < frameTimeInterval)
            {
                // Waiting
                ;
            }

            lastFPSSynchronization = SDL_GetTicks();

            if (machine.saveGameRequest)
            {
                machine.saveGameRequest = false;
                machine.saveGame(CPUInterruptDeltaCycles);
            }

            if (machine.loadGameRequest)
            {
                machine.loadGameRequest = false;
                machine.loadGame(CPUInterruptDeltaCycles);

                // Remove pending keyboard events
                SDL_FlushEvent(SDL_KEYDOWN);
                SDL_FlushEvent(SDL_KEYUP);
                SDL_PumpEvents();
            }
        }

        // Reset if requested
        if (machine.resetRequest)
        {
            machine.resetRequest = false;
            machine.resetMachine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new surface and a new texture every frame. Yeah it's going to be slow, creating textures is a ridiculously slow operation. Don't do it so often.

If you need to write pixels directly, create a texture of the right size once (with `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING`) and then use `SDL_LockTexture` and `SDL_UnlockTexture` to update it (note: don't use `SDL_UpdateTexture` for this, it's not really much - if at all - better than recreating the texture performance wise). I'm guessing the windows version is fast "by accident" because your driver implementation notices you're doing something strange and quietly ignores what you're telling it to do and does something faster.

Of course without looking at the code it's hard to say this is the *only* problem with it, but this is pretty likely to be a (or maybe even the) bottleneck.

Comment: As I wrote on the first post, if I comment out `machine.createFrame()` and `machine.showFrame()` calls in the main loop the game is still slow. The problem is not there. I tried to use lock/unlock functions but my texture is never update, 
however the problem is not there

Comment: @Francesco Then why is it in the question, but the thing where you think your problem is isn't?